# possible to create a multiline text file in codeigniter force_download function?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have tried this code with '\n' and '\r' and '\r\n' instead of `'<br/>'`.
but it displayed as it is instead of converting it to new line.
anybody please help me on this?

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = 'Here is some text!';
$data .= '<br/> Here is some text!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';
force_download($name, $data,TRUE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = "Here is some text! \n";
$data .= 'Here is some more text in new line!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';
force_download($name, $data,TRUE);
```

`'\n'` in single quotes is a literal `\n`.

`"\n"` in double quotes is interpreted as a `line break`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thank you Praveen. I got the answer and for got to update

Comment: Mark it as answer then... you know how to mark... @Premjith

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = "Here is some text! \n";
$data .= 'Here is some text!';
$name = 'mytext.txt';
force_download($name, $data,TRUE);
```